# Notify When Update(s) Performed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm looking to create a tally of the number of core, theme and plugin updates performed on a given WP installation. I envisage that this would involve creating an option into which I store and int value that is incremented every time a core, theme &/or plugin update is successfully performed.

To enable this I was hoping for some hooks are called when each of these update types are performed. However, I can't seem to find any relevant hooks for plugin and theme updates.

For core updates, it looks like I can simply increment the relevant options field whenever the '_core_updated_successfully' hook is called.

Are there any relevant hooks available for plugins and themes? 
Can you suggest an alternative methodology?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the [upgrader_process_complete](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete) action hook. it runs when the download process for a plugin install or update finishes. It takes a `type` parameter for `core`, `plugin` or `theme`.

Comment: I'll take a look at that asap. Thanks & Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I needed. However, the documentation you linked to is out of date and the values returned have significantly changed. Here's the most recent info on this hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete-2/